# Compare system Day and DateTime

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I'm using the code below to compare two Times:

```
DateTime systemtime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timestart = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimestart.Text);
DateTime timeend = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeend.Text);

if (systemtime < timestart || systemtime > timeend)
{
    MessageBox.Show("not auth.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("auth.");
}
```

But I also want to compare the current day. For example, if today is Monday or Thursday, the user is authenticated, not if otherwise. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your questions about comparing `DayOfWeek` to a string, you can either parse your string into a `DayOfWeek`, e.g. `(DayOfWeek) Enum.Parse(typeof (DayOfWeek), "Monday")` or compare as a string: `systemtime.DayOfWeek.ToString()`

Comment: How do i do it exactly? Both my TimeStart, TimeEnd and Day are of String data types.

Comment: How do I get what the current day is? If there is DateTime.Now, how am I supposed to get the DayOfWeek for today? I need to compare it to some string inside a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime systemtime = DateTime.Now;
if(systemtime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now do I convert a string to DayOfWeek?

Comment: @CantHandleMeBabe DayOfWeek someDay;
 DayOfWeek.TryParse("monday", true, out someDay)

Comment: @CantHandleMeBabe it's just an enum. you can use any way of parsing - like above or any another method like var yourDay = Enum.Parse(typeof (DayOfWeek), "monday"); etc etc

Comment: Why does it says **Error 1 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DayOfWeek' and 'object'**?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie This is the code, **DayOfWeek systemday = Convert.ToString(systemtime.DayOfWeek);**

Comment: How do I get what the current day is? If there is DateTime.Now, how am I supposed to get the DayOfWeek for today? I need to compare it to some string inside a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

`timestart.DayOfWeek` will give you values like `DayOfWeek.Thursday` or `DayOfWeek.Friday` etc.

See here for documentation and an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but how do I compare it if it's a string?

Comment: The other comments have shown you how to convert a `DayOfWeek` to `String`. If you already have a string such as `Friday` you can also compare that with `timestart.DayOfWeek.ToString()`

Comment: How do i do it exactly? Both my TimeStart, TimeEnd and Day are of String data types.

Comment: How do I get what the current day is? If there is DateTime.Now, how am I supposed to get the DayOfWeek for today? I need to compare it to some string inside a textbox.

Comment: `if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == StringInsideTextBox) ...`

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` object will have a property `DayOfWeek`.
You could just compare the string.

Comment: Technically, its an enumeration instead of a string.

Comment: How do I get what the current day is? If there is DateTime.Now, how am I supposed to get the DayOfWeek for today? I need to compare it to some string inside a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var systemtime = DateTime.Now;
var start = "Monday";
var finish = "Wednesday";
DayOfWeek startDay;
if (!Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(start ,out startDay))
{
    //handle parse error 
}
DayOfWeek finishDay;
if (!Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(finish, out finishDay))
{
    //handle parse error
}

if (systemtime.DayOfWeek < startDay || systemtime.DayOfWeek > finishDay)
{
    MessageBox.Show("not auth.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("auth.");
}
```